# How to get all dropdown's (listBox) values from a cell using aspose

Tags: java, listbox, aspose

I have a pre-populated excel file. Some cells there are dropdowns with values. I want using aspose for Java get all values from these dropdowns.
Seems ListBox - is what I need to work with, but I only found examples how to create listBox (http://www.aspose.com/api/java/cells/com.aspose.cells/classes/ListBox), but not how to initialize existing one.

I tried to assignt cell to listBox as following:

```
ListBox listBox = getCellsCollection().get(rowNum - offset, getColumnIndex(uniqueColumnName);
```

But got an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from Cell to ListBox

Initializing ListBox worked this way:

```
Worksheet sheet = book.getWorksheets().get(0);
    ListBox listBox = (ListBox) sheet.getShapes().addShape(MsoDrawingType.LIST_BOX,7, 0, 1,0, 1, 1);
     listBox.setPlacement(PlacementType.FREE_FLOATING);
     listBox.setLinkedCell("D8");
```

But non of the getAlternativeText(), getSelectedCells(), getCharacters() give me what I need (all return null).
P.S. I dont really understand the values 7, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1 in adding a shape, but that should mean 'D8' cell in my understanding.

When I try to get values from a cell - I only get displayed one and not the full list (or I don't know how to get it right).

How using aspose for Java I can get all values from existing dropdown in excel file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have answered this question in the Aspose.Cells forum. Please see the reply and solution at this post.

http://www.aspose.com/community/forums/permalink/675036/675109/showthread.aspx#675109

Let us know if it is helpful for you and resolves your issue. If you still find any problem, then please feel free to post in Aspose.Cells forum or at this stackoverflow page.

*Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose*

Comment: Thank you so much, that answered my question.